# Message 088 code usage

Tags: alien-isolation

In Gemini Exoplanet Solutions, the terminal in the dark room down the hall from Product Storage,  I'm given message 088 Maintenance Systems.  This message includes a code and mentions possibly needing it to enable the distribution system

However, I was able to restart the power distribution system without ever seeing anywhere to use it.

What exactly is this code used for?

Edit: I should note that I'm playing on Normal difficulty.

Side note: Don't confuse this for the code from message 094, which you get from one of the upstairs computers in the same area... that one opens the wall drawer thing nearby.

Comment: I'm pretty much at that point. If you the mean code from the dark room just through the door where you find the plasma cutter, and the the utility action on the computer by the android just around the corner from that, then I can confirm you can reactivate the power without having read the code (or any of the messages) from that PC in the dark room.

Comment: Agreed: I've just finished that area (more or less - I got eaten on the way out) and I never had to enter that code. The most relevant bit would be when you're activating the large power column in the depot room; the option you use to activate the android that actually turns it on matches one of the messages from that PC. But I didn't have to enter the code to do the previous action.

Comment: What's the code it contains? Is is 7789?

Comment: @Keith It's `8897` in my game.

Comment: Incidentally, I never did find out what this code was for... but I haven't gone back there yet to do a Metroid-style "hunt for the items I missed" thing yet.

Answer (score -2):

I'm not as far along in the game as you, but from what I've seen of the game I think most of the keycodes or other codes you get are entered automatically; in other words, you need to pick up the information that says the code on it, but you don't actually need to remember the code yourself, Ripley does it for you. You probably already used the code without realizing it.

Comment: Not sure which version of the game you're playing, but on Normal difficulty on the PC version, I have to manually enter codes.  Which is annoying the first time you need to do it as the Alien is stalking you in a small area and several doors can be unlocked with the same code.

Comment: I'm actually playing on Hard, PC. I only remember having to enter exactly one code, which I found odd at the time. Not counting the security tuner mini game, of course.

Comment: Well, the code I'm referring to is the one you get from one of the doctors computers in the Psychiatric ward things... fairly early on, as it's during the first sequence where the Alien is chasing you around.  I doubt it's because I'm using an Xbox 360 controller, but I can't rule it out.

Comment: This is incorrect - you have to manually enter every code you come across, you can't select the keyboard until you've read the message that contains the code, and then you have to remember it and enter it manually while listening out for the Alien.